# Amazon RDS instance in EBS: Access Denied when trying from Java application in Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, amazon-rds

I created an EBS instance including the RDS instance based on MySQL.

I have access to the EC2 instance using SSH via PuTTY and using the MySQL Workbench I've got access to the RDS instance as well and I can create tables and insert data in them.

I developed a Java application using Netbeans 7.3.1 and when I run the application locally while connecting to the MySQL instance on RDS the application shows the same problem although I can connect to MySQL from within Netbeans without a problem, ie I can connect to the database. But as soon as I deploy my simple application onto EBS and run the same application I get the error "Access denied for user ''@'' (using password: YES)"

I added the IP to the Security Group of my RDS instance as well as the EBS instance. Just to be sure.

Still I got the Access Denied error. The JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING environment variable I've set up is "jdbc:mysql://.cdydcnmtkkhw.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/ebdb?user=&password="
When I use any of the tools to connect to this database with that information all works, when I try to connect from my Java application running in Tomcat, I get the Access Denied message.

The Java call I'm using is:

```
private java.sql.Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnect);
```

Comment: You've redacted parts of the error message, correct?  It's fine if you did (better if you did), just want to be clear.  Because it *should* say something like `Access denied for user 'some-user'@'some-host' (using password: YES)` -- are the `some-user` and `some-host` parts in your error message what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like the stock standard cannot connect to mysql error and nothing really to do with EC2 as you have set up you security group.

See the [mysql link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html).  which explains about

`SET PASSWORD FOR 'abe'@'host_name' = PASSWORD('eagle');`